# Solving linear systems of equations modulo a prime power

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I am interested in knowing if there is a general theory for solving linear systems of equations modulo a prime power $p^k$. Such questions have been asked here before:

- [Solving system of linear equations involving modulo power of 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800458/solving-system-of-linear-equations-involving-modulo-power-of-2)
- [System of linear congruences modulo a prime power](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986201/system-of-linear-congruences-modulo-a-prime-power)

but none of them is satisfactory since the first one only points to other not-exactly-relevant questions, and the second points to Gaussian elimination, which AFAIK [only gets as general as working over fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Generalizations).

I think that a reasonable and generic way of finding such solutions is by using a generalization of [Hensel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel_lemma) to multivariate equations, but before I dive into such approach I would like to know if there is not an off-the-shelf solution I could use.

Thanks!